# I am not able to delete any component on any aem pages

Tags: content-management-system, aem, sling, aem-6

It is not deleting from the aem page, when i clicked on delete option in aem pages
My components are not getting deleted in all aem pages. How to solve this issue [this the sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS4uC.png)

I had clicked to delete on this component but its not getting deleting.

Comment: Please check if you have access to delete components.

Comment: In addition to what @Sadistic mentioned, please also check the the console output in the browser as well as the server logs - especially if you don't understand ACLs.